# DVC mixed lightning pytorch step batch size

Tags: dvcs, pytorch-lightning, dvc

I am using logging with data version control (DVCLiveLogger) with lightning pytorch and my problem is that my batch size does not stay fixed across all the steps. and so every time it is a random size just like below. Is there a reason why this happens? They are approximately close but it is not the batch size that I gave to the data module.

len(input_nodes)
1779
len(input_nodes)
1769
len(input_nodes)
1761

Thank you :)

I tried passing batch size explicitly through lightning data module, yet same problem occured.

Answer (score 1):

I work on DVC/DVCLive. Could you share a code example to see how you set your batch size and log it? DVCLive should not be doing anything but saving info about the training, so it shouldn't impact the batch size, which should come from your data loader.

Comment: hello, thanks for following up! an update about this issue, I happen to use two other libraries that conflicted with each other and none was dvc.